# edit aggregate polygons

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, editing, merge

i have one file, with 32000 record ,its polygons for city ,when i want to merge some polygons for get one rooftop polygon from many polygons  ,this new polygon remove or it's have unwanted lines between the old polygons ,
how i can to merge polygons for get aggregate polygon ?
i need edit by hand not tools ,
[image]
thanks ;

Answer (score 1):

The remaining lines are there because your topology is not correct (very small gap between two polygon boundaries). Before you use the "merge" in edition, you should run "[integrate](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000002s000000)" to clean your dataset. Once you have done that, you should not have artefacts after merging adjacent polygons.

Comment: Your idea is making me realize that the gaps in the linework aren't just symbology and that the data's kind of a mess. I would be impressed if any single command can handle all the issues, esp w/out coding given [responses to questions like this](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31657/algorithm-to-fill-the-gaps-adjacent-to-parcels) and the fact that this person has ~32K features.

Comment: this is not the same issue. You are pointing to a specific editing task to CREATE new polygons. In this case, the problem comes from topological errors that can probably be solved by merging vertices based on a small tolerance. If he gaps are not just symbology, there there would not be any polygon.

Comment: Sounds like I'm not understanding the image, then. Seems like there are polylines that look like polygons, but are not because there all kinds of gaps. Therefore, the editing job isn't one of simply aggregating polygons (that I thought the OP was after). It's either cleaning polylines up to form polygons for aggregation or manually selecting and deleting a somewhat daunting number of polylines.

Comment: yes ,its work very good with integrate tool ,  thank you very much