# Joining separate parcels based on group ID into one large group

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-join

What tool would I use to group many parcels into its own respective group. For example, if parcels A, B , C have group ID of 1 then I would like to have parcels A, B, and C combined into one larger parcel. Is there a tool that does this without me manually digitizing it?

Also, I have another layer called street center lines, and would like the larger parcel to have the street center line as its boundary if it is lying next to a street center line.

Please refer to the images below

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQMQN.jpg

The first photo shows many parcels that have the same ID group.

[image]

The second photo shows a close up view of street center lines next to the parcels.

[image]

The third photo shows the desired result. Each larger grouped parcel has a boundary that is next to each other.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To combine features into one larger feature based on the value of a particular field, use a [Dissolve](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/coverage-toolbox/dissolve.htm) operation.

According to the help,

> [Dissolve] creates a new coverage by merging adjacent polygons,
>   lines, or regions that have the same value for a specified item.

[image]

Comment: Because the dissolved polygons aren't touching, there may be a need to incorporate a convex/concave hull on the groupings as well to get something close to the desired output.

Comment: Ah, I missed that piece. There are some reasonable ideas here: [Algorithm to fill the gaps adjacent to parcels](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31657/algorithm-to-fill-the-gaps-adjacent-to-parcels).